# angularjs ui bootstrap modification to popover

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i am using ng-repeat to create some buttons, and using ng-mouseenter to trigger a function I have in the controller.
below is the original code:

---

```
Inside html: sample button element
<button class="btn btn-black" ng-mouseover="hoverIn(counter.id)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
Tips
</button>
<div ng-show="hoverEdit" class="popover left">{{returned object from hoverIn}}

Inside angular.js file
$scope.hoverIn = function(counter_id){
    $http.get(); get json object from mysql
    this.hoverEdit = true;
}
$scope.hoverOut = function(){
    this.hoverEdit = false;
}
```

I simplified a lot of this code, but this is the basic idea. All the functions are working well. except the css for hovering is very messed because the element position:absolute. it got very messy.
so I was searching on the web, and found ui-bootstrap's popover. So I change my code to this new one below:

---

```
<button ng-mouseenter="hoverIn(counter.id)" 
uib-popover-template="TipPopover.templateUrl" popover-placement="left"  popover-trigger="mouseenter"
popover-title="Tips:" type="button" class="btn btn-black">Tips</button>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="PopoverTipTemplate.html">
    <div ng-repeat="tip in tips" ng-cloak>{{tip.tip}}</div>
</script>
```

All the css are perfect, but I'm not sure how to make the 'popover-trigger="mouseenter"' to run my hoverIn() function. So i tried putting in the ng-mouseenter="hoverIn()" into it. and magically it works. 
but the problem is there is a clear delay that the hoverIn() function is runned after the mouseenter. I could see the content changing after I hover onto the element. I don't think my original code did this, because I'm showing the div(setting hoverEdit to true) after I've got the json object from mysql.
Does anyone know a better way to do this?